# OPEN CTI XML definition file What is it and how it works?

Tags: apex, xml, cti

I'm working now with open CTI and my question is related to the CTI XML definition file. I would like to know how it works, I saw it has many sections and many items, but it affects my code, what can I do with this file (except import it as Call Center)?. I'm new with all this telephony things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call center definition file provides the configuration for your softphone adapter - Salesforce just uses it to generate the page that allows the configuration to be changed.

The documentation isn't fantastic around this, but there's a reasonable overview at:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_call_def_file.htm

Its also worth having a look at the wiki article for open cti on developerforce:

https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Open_CTI

The definition file in this case is already present due to the packaging, but you can see from the sample page and code how it is used.